# Launching after update to Spyder 3.1.4 impossible

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, codec

I have a problem after updating of Spyder in the distribution of Anaconda to version 3.1.4 with "conda -update spyder". After the update, I'm not able to start Spyder. It loads until the message "Setting up main window ..." and then it crashes.

In the console, I get the following output with the command:
spyder --show-console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3011, in main
mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
File "D:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 2913, in run_spyder
main.setup()
File "D:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 1110, in setup
self.setup_layout(default=False)
File "D:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 1385, in setup_layout
self.setup_default_layouts('default', settings)
File "D:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 1564, in setup_default_layouts
widget.toggle_view(True)
File "D:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 692, in toggle_view
self.create_new_client(give_focus=False)
File "D:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 925, in create_new_client
self.connect_client_to_kernel(client)
File "D:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 944, in connect_client_to_kernel
stderr_file)
File "D:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 1342, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client kernel_manager._kernel_spec = self.create_kernel_spec()
File "D:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 1321, in create_kernel_spec
uv = to_text_string(v)
File "D:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\py3compat.py", line 135, in to_text_string
return unicode(obj)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I reinstalled everything, i.e. Anaconda as well as Spyder. With the old version of Spyder I never had any issues...

Thanks for your help folks!

Comment: Please run `spyder --reset` in a terminal and try again. That should fix your problem.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it did not help. Spyder still doesn't start and shows the same error as posted above.

Comment: Ok, I know now where this bug is coming from. I'll fix it for Spyder 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder developer here*) This is a [bug](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4632) in Spyder and it will be fixed in Spyder **3.2** (to be released during June or July/2017).

Comment: Thank's for this information! I'm looking forward to get the updated version.